# Redirect url one domain to another domain use kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, url, redirect, kubernetes-ingress

I want to redirect the url from one domain to another domain.

1. Like "https://example.com" (Domain A) To "https://sample.com (Domain B). For that we need to use middleware in kubernetes.
2. To redirect url to Domain A - in Internet to Domain B - In intranet in kubernetes.

Comment: Kubernetes normally just manages containers across multiple systems.  Is there specific software or an Ingress configuration you're using that would deal with HTTP traffic?  What have you tried so far?

Comment: Might be useful https://medium.com/@harsh.manvar111/kubernetes-ingress-domain-redirect-4595e9030a2c